# Edittext multiline can't focus other line except first line

Tags: android, layout, android-edittext, multiline

I'm a android newbie. I have a problem with edittext multiline in android, It just select first line and can't focus other lines. My code:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/etQuestion"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
        android:background="#fff"
        android:gravity="top|left" 
        android:hint="My text"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:textColorHint="#aaa"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:minHeight="400dp" 
         />
```

Any suggest for me, please

Comment: Add this android:selectAllOnFocus="true"

Comment: it not working for me, can give me other sugesst?